# Looking for specific sound clips website

Tags: product-identification, fantasy, sound-effects

Less than a year ago I found out about a relatively small website with short audio clips and background sound effects designed for fantasy tabletop RPGs (all the usual suspects were there, e.g., dragon roar, tavern chatter, spooky cave, sword clash...). The website was designed as a grid of icons, similar to the home page of a smartphone. The icons were somewhat realistic but still comic-book-like, perhaps like something out of Penny Arcade. I believe it was possible to mix two or more sounds by tapping them in succession.

Sadly, I've lost the URL and I can't remember the name of the website, or even how I came across it. Does anybody know which website this is?

Comment: Sadly, there is little to little here that would allow a positive identification as one specific sound clip site. Is there anything specific you remember that might differentiate the site from others?

Comment: Sadly indeed, the regular grid of quasi-hand-drawn round icons is the most distinctive thing I remember, along with the nice ability to "mix" tracks on the fly. On the other hand, absolutely none of the many websites I looked at over the past few days, looking for this particular one, looked anything close to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! It’s https://tabletopy.com. Still in development, you can leave feedback on a recent reddit thread (https://reddit.com/r/InternetIsBeautiful/comments/qgrfvz/beautifully_designed_free_soundboard_to).

Answer (score 5):

It can be the [Tabletop Audio SoundPad](https://tabletopaudio.com/soundpad.html):

> a relatively small website with short audio clips and background sound effects designed for fantasy tabletop RPGs

It was created by [dijon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3206/dijon) specifically for TTRPGs and contains short audio clips and background sounds.

> The website was designed as a grid of icons, similar to the home page of a smartphone. The icons were somewhat realistic but still comic-book-like

A typical soundpad looks like this:
[image: the website screenshot]

> I believe it was possible to mix two or more sounds by tapping them in succession.

You can tap two or more "play" buttons and mix several sounds together.

Comment: Thanks, that was not what I was originally looking for, but this seems great as well.